# Number of leap years between two given years (inclusive)

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

Is there a better way to calculate the number of leap years between two given years? I want to make my code shorter (in Python). Do you have any suggestions?

Here is my solution:

```python
i=int
r=raw_input
t=i(r())
while t:
 b,d=map(i,r().split())
 c=0
 for y in range(b,d+1):
  if y%400==0 or y%4==0 and y%100:c+=1
 print c
 t-=1
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Would you mind if I edited your post to conform to our standards?

Comment: Specifying python is a bit restrictive. Also, you could just say "inclusive" in the title.

Comment: Looking at the question, I'm not sure what do you want to ask, as you say "is there a better way" and "in python" so you may want to ask a [tag:tips] question, but I'm not sure. I've VTC as unclear question.

Comment: Note to close-voter: this question is on-topic as a tips question, albeit with places for improvement in clarity.

Comment: You ask for a *way to calculate the number of leap years between two given years*, but your code is doing much more than just that. If there are specific input/output formats we have to respect, we have to know about them.

Answer (score 6):

#### Quick wins (-6 bytes)

Using `i=int` actually costs 2 bytes, because the shortened expression is only used twice in the code. We can save 4 other bytes by using `<1` instead of `==0` and removing useless whitespace.

```python
r=raw_input
t=int(r())
while t:
 b,d=map(int,r().split())
 c=0
 for y in range(b,d+1):
  if y%400<1or y%4<1and y%100:c+=1
 print c
 t-=1
```

#### Getting rid of the for loop (-7 bytes)

Using **sum()**, **map()** and a lambda is shorter than a **for** loop with an additional variable. However, we need an explicit test on `y%100` to turn the result into a boolean.

```python
r=raw_input
t=int(r())
while t:
 b,d=map(int,r().split())
 print sum(map(lambda y:y%400<1or y%4<1and y%100>0,range(b,d+1)))
 t-=1
```

#### Using a built-in function and tweaking the way input is taken (-16 bytes)

Finally, importing and using `calendar.isleap` saves 7 more bytes. `input()` instead of `int(r())` saves another byte. Dropping `r=raw_input` and using it directly in the loop saves another 4 bytes. Finally, removing all unnecessary newlines saves 4 bytes too.

```python
from calendar import*
t=input()
while t:b,d=map(int,raw_input().split());print sum(map(isleap,range(b,d+1)));t-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBDsIgEIXhPaeYJWhtoCu14SwGLVoSGCYwTdPTIzGu3uL/Hh28Zpxae5ec4OWix8UVCIly4ZNgG5A2lkrsa4ge@P4cFpscyYA8FLc//n2sFENfNVPpCeqW5I/V6B11iR8v@/dsVDd8saY1I8xNa5i0uX4B)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @user202729*

#### Not using a built-in function anymore... (-3 bytes)

```python
t=input()
while t:b,d=map(int,raw_input().split());print sum(y%400<1or y%4<1<=y%100for y in range(b,d+1));t-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzNCoMwEITvPsVehEht2ZUe@pM8i6TU1gWNS1yRPH0aoaf5ho8ZSTouoctZHQfZ1DTVPvI0gD5e7dvNXgwHbaPf@7@/rDJxyeYpsShYt9mk@opoaYlQyJJ1qSbEz9GBA0QfvoMpfycqMz07ypkquiNCh3T7AQ)

All these changes have shortened the source code to **110 bytes**.

Comment: `from calendar import*` saves 3 more bytes.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! I've turned this into community wiki, so feel free to edit it further.

Comment: BTW if the OP says that taking input in the form `t \n b, d` is allowed, then `b,d=input()` saves a bunch of bytes